# Why does form calculation return Nan?

Tags: javascript, nan

Apologies as I am relatively new to Javascript.
I have a form returning 2 values, and the first value (totalprice) works fine.
For the second value the page has to be refreshed or returns a Nan error
My Javascript code is:

```js
var pallet_prices = [3.5, 2.75, 2.60, 2.50, 2.25, 2.00];
var order_price = [1.30, 1.15, 1.10, 1.05, 1.00, 0.93];
var extra_cost = [0.55, 0.45, 0.40, 0.40, 0.38, 0.35];
var items_quantity = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

var item_charge = 0;
var item_index = 0;
var weekly_quantity = 0;

var item_charge = parseFloat(item_charge);
var item_index = parseFloat(item_index);
var weekly_quantity = parseFloat(weekly_quantity);

// uncertain if these variables need to be converted to numbers ...  
// var pallet_prices = parseFloat(pallet_prices);
// var order_price = parseFloat(order_price);
// var extra_cost = parseFloat(extra_cost);
// var items_quantity = parseFloat(items_quantity);

function clear_radio_buttons() {
  var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = inp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if ('radio' === inp[i].type) inp[i].checked = false;
  }
}

function reset_select_fields() {
  var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = inp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if ('select' === inp[i].type) inp[i].checked = false;
  }

}

function getpalletPrice() {
  var palletPrice = 0;
  var pallet_index = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["fulfilment"];
  var nopallets = theForm.elements["nopallets"];
  for (var i = 0; i < nopallets.length; i++) {
    if (nopallets[i].checked) {
      pallet_index = i; //Get index number of pallet prices array for this selection
      break;
    }
  }
  return pallet_index;

}

function get_no_orders() {
  //var week_orders;
  var week_orders_index = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["fulfilment"];
  var number_orders = theForm.elements["number_orders"];
  for (var i = 0; i < number_orders.length; i++) {
    if (number_orders[i].checked) {
      week_orders_index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return week_orders_index;
}

function get_items_per_order() {
  var items_quantity = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["fulfilment"];
  var no_of_items = theForm.elements["no_of_items"];
  for (var i = 0; i < no_of_items.length; i++) {
    if (no_of_items[i].checked) {
      items_quantity = no_of_items[i].value;

      break;
    }
  }

  return items_quantity;
}

function calculateTotal() {
  //Here we get the total price by calling our function
  //Each function returns an index number so by calling them we can add the values they represent together

  var pallet_index = getpalletPrice(); // Get the index number of the price array
  palletPrice = pallet_prices[pallet_index]; // Get the charge from the pallet_prices array

  //display the result
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  // divobj.innerHTML = "Storage Price per Pallet £"+palletPrice;   // Display the pallet storage charge
  divobj.innerHTML = "Storage Price per Pallet £" + parseFloat(palletPrice).toFixed(2); // Display the pallet storage charge
  // Note this all falls down if the result is not displayed at this point


  // Now get the charge for the number of orders per week and the extra cost per item for this quantity of orders
  weekly_order_quantity = get_no_orders();
  extra_cost = extra_cost[weekly_order_quantity];
  order_price = order_price[weekly_order_quantity];
  //items_quantity = get_items_per_order();

  // Now get the number of items for the order
  //items_index = get_items_per_order();  // This is not returning a valid number
  //items_index = 5;  // Test with a valid number
  //items_index = document.getElementById("no_of_items").value;

  // Calculate total ordering charge
  // 
  week_orders = 0; // Define the display variable

  /*        // week_orders is calculated by the formula 
            // week_orders = Charge for Volume Quantity + (No of Items per order quantity - 1) * Extra Cost for Number of Orders per week Charge
            // e.g 55 items: Charge for 55 Orders per week = 1.05, Items per Individual Order Quantity = 8, Extra Cost for 55 Orders per week = 0.40
            // week_orders = £1.05 + (8-1) * £0.40 = £1.05 + 7 * £0.40 = £3.85
  */

  //week_orders = order_price;  // Test - Variable is defined & usable
  //week_orders = extra_cost;   // Test - Variable is defined & usable
  // week_orders = items_index;  // Test - Variable not defined/working
  //Final calculation for display Comment out for testing!!!
  items_index = document.getElementById("no_of_items").value;
  week_orders = order_price + extra_cost * (items_index - 1);



  // NOTE WE NEED TO RESET THE FORM AFTER DISPLAY OR VARIABLES NOT VALID FOR CALCULATION

  //display the result
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice1');
  divobj.style.display = 'block';
  // divobj.innerHTML = "Price per Order £"+week_orders;       // Display the total Order cost
  divobj.innerHTML = "Price per Order £" + parseFloat(week_orders).toFixed(2); // Display the total Order cost

  reset_select_fields();

}

function hideTotal() {
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
  divobj.style.display = 'none';
}

function clear_screen() {
  location.reload();
}


function hideTotal1() {
  var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice1');
  divobj.style.display = 'none';
}

function hideTotals() {
  hideTotal();
  hideTotal1();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Fulfilment Calculator</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formcalculations.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="styles/fulfilment.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body onLoad='hideTotals()' ;>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div>
      <form action="" id="fulfilment" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div class="cont_order">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Calculate Pallet Storage Price</legend>
            <label>Select Number of Pallets Stored</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="nopallets" value="1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1 to 5 stored per week</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="nopallets" value="6" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 6 to 25 stored per week</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="nopallets" value="26" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 26 to 50 stored per week</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="nopallets" value="51" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 51 to 100 stored per week</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="nopallets" value="101" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 101 to 200 stored per week</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="nopallets" value="200" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 200+ stored per week</label><br/>
            <br/>
            <div id="totalPrice"></div>
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset>
            <legend>How many items on your order?</legend>

            <select id="no_of_items" name='no_of_items'>
              <option value="None" autofocus selected disabled>Select No. of Items</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset>
            <legend>How many orders each week?</legend>

            <label>Number of Orders per Week</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="number_orders" value="1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1 to 10 orders per week</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="number_orders" value="11" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 11 to 25 orders per week</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="number_orders" value="26" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 26 to 50 orders per week</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="number_orders" value="51" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 51 to 100 orders per week</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="number_orders" value="101" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 101 to 200 orders per week</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="number_orders" value="201" onclick="calculateTotal()" /> 201+ orders per week</label><br/>
            <br/>
            <div id="totalPrice1"></div>
            <a onClick="window.location.reload()">Refresh</a>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="cont_order">
          <fieldset>
            <br>
            <div class="cont_details">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Contact Details</legend>
                <label for='name'>Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name='name' />
                <br/>
                <label for='address'>Address</label>
                <input type="text" id="address" name='address' />
                <br/>
                <label for='phonenumber'>Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name='phonenumber' />
                <br/>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal3()" />
            <input type </form>
        </div>
        <!--End of wrap-->
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated
The first part of the form works as expected, but the sceond, althought the maths is cirrect gives a NaN unless the page is refreshed.

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateTotal3 is not defined"`

Comment: That's a *lot* of code. You need to provide a [mcve] (emphasis on the *minimal*). Following the advice behind that link to break the problem down is likely to lead you to a solution without needing other contributors.

Comment: Also never call anything submit in a form - it will hide the DOM submit event handler - also use the submit event instead of a submit button click event

Comment: Like this: `window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("fulfilment").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calculateTotal();
  })
})`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem here:

```
  items_index = document.getElementById("no_of_items").value;
  week_orders = order_price + extra_cost * (items_index - 1);
```

`items_index` is a string...
`(items_index - 1)` will return `NaN` if `items_index` is not a number-in-a-string.
Could also be if `order_price` or `extra_cost` are not numbers/number-in-a-string.